# Storing bitmap data in an integer array for speed?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I am using Cocoa/Objective-C and I am using NSBitmapImageRep getPixel:atX:y: to test whether R is 0 or 255. That is the only piece of data I need (the bitmap is only black and white).

I am noticing that this one function is the biggest draw on CPU power in my application, accounting for something like 95% of the overhead. Would it be faster for me to preload the bitmap into a 2 dimensional integer array

```
NSUInteger pixels[1280][1024];
```

and read the values like so:

```
if(pixels[x][y]!=0){
//....do stuff
}
```

?

Comment: I just did, now my application uses 82.5% less CPU power to accomplish the same thing... Wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Objective-C or the NSBitmapImageRep object, but a reasonable guess is that the `getPixel` routine employs clipping to avoid reading outside of memory, which could a possible slowdown (among other things).

Have a look inside it and see what it does.

(**update**)
Having learnt that this is Apple code, you probably *can't* take a look inside it.
However, the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/getPixel%3aatX%3ay%3a) for `NSBitmapImageRep_Class` seems to indicate that `getPixel:atX:y:` performs at least some type magic. You could test if the result is clipped by accessing a pixel outside of the image boundary and observing the result.

The [bitmapData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/bitmapData) seems to be something you'd be interested in: get the pointer to the data, then read the array yourself avoiding type conversion or clipping.

Comment: How do I look inside it? all I can find is the header file :(

Comment: Thanks for following up on that. I will try that method too (in reference to scanning the bitmapData directly).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that might be helpful could be converting the data into something more "dense". Since you're only interested in a single bit per pixel location, it doesn't make sense to store more than that. Storing more data than necessary means you get less usage out of your cache, which can really slow things down if the image is big and/or the accesses very random.

For instance, you could use the platform's largest "native" integer and pack in the pixels to use a single bit for each pixel. That will make the access a bit more involved since you need to do a single-bit testing, but it might be a win.

You would do something like this:

```
uint32_t image[HEIGHT * ((WIDTH + 31) / 32)];
```

Then initialize this array by using the slow getter method, once per pixel. Then you can read out the value of a pixel using something like `image[y * ((WIDTH + 31) / 32) + (x / 32)] & (1 << (x & 31))`.

I'm being vague ("might", "can" and so on) since it really depends on your access pattern, the size of the image, and other things. You should probably test it.

Comment: I simply placed each pixel's R value in an unsigned long array (that is the data type that - getPixel uses) and it has sped up my application by 82.5%. This is so significant that I may not need to go any further. I might try your method here, but it concerns me that division is such a slow operation, I am not sure your method would be significantly faster than just having a 2 dimensional array. I don't know for sure though, as I barely know anything about how array data is referenced, but it just seems like finding x,y is faster than running all those calculations to find just x.

Comment: Instead of dividing by 32, you could shift bits to right 5 times and comes to the same thing : replace `/ 32` by `>> 5` .

Comment: I was experimenting with bitshifting for division earlier but it appears that xCode already utilizes that shortcut. Unfortunately, the results were still significantly slower than other operations.